# JavaScript: Best Way to return true if found values repeated in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to find duplicate values in a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array)

Let's say I have an array with thousands of elements and

I want to `return true` if there are **2 or more elements with the same value**.

I know I can run a `for loop` and do a check on every pair of elements to find the answer.

**But is there a faster way? And what's the best way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the [Element Distinctness Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem). You can read about it, but with only 1000 elements, the optimizations are probably not worth it.

If you really want to optimize it, you can push the elements into a hash table and check if collisions are duplicates. This will give you O(n) on average (amortized), but O(n^2) in worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Sort it (whatever the comparator) and then scan. O(n log(n)).

Comment: This problem has a O(n) solution, see my answer

Comment: Sure it has, but requires O(n) memory (and with _"thousands of elements"_ this might or might not be a considerable impact.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest way would be to use the native methods. `inArray` is not one of them.
You could use `indexOf` and default to a for loop if that method doens't exists (older browsers).

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster way. It's concrete implementation depends on what you have in the array. But the idea is the pseudo code below:

let's say you have an `id(element)` function that returns a string identifier of your element.

```
var map = {};

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var currentId = id(myArray[i]);
    if(map.hasOwnProperty(id)) return true;
    map[id] = true;
}
```

The complexity here is linear.

If you don't have a natural id, you can either build one from the properties which identify the object, or do something smarter... the smartest thing you can do here is reimplementing a hashmap.

Comment: This is linear on average, but in the presence of hash collisions, this might deteriorate to quadratic.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov that was stupid, tx

Comment: @Oleksi id here is not a hash. Do you mean that the native javascript hashmap's performance may degrade to quadratic in some cases ? If so, what can we say about the worse case complexity of the sort... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Array.prototype.elementsNotDistinct = function () {
    var i, j, length = this.length - 1;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j <= length; j++)
            if (this[i] === this[j]) return true;

    return false;
};
```

Then if you have an array called `a` all you need to do is:

```
if (a.elementsNotDistinct()) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Array`'s built in `indexOf` operation will work brilliantly for you (depending on the data you need to sort )

```
// Filter out all instances that occur twice or more.

var example = [ 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 5, 3 ];
var result = Array.filter( function ( element ) {
    return this.indexOf( element ) >= 2;
}  
// result is an array of [3,5]

return result.length === 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the array and set an object key equal to the element found in the array (converted in a string). If your key already exists then you have found two element into the array with a duplicated value

```
function isAllDistinct() {
    var elements  = { },
        yourarray = [...];

    for (i=0, l=yourarray.length; i < l; i++) {
       var key = yourarray[i] + '';  // alternative to yourarray[i].toString()
       if (!elements[key]) {
         elements[key] = 1;
       }
       else {
         return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Complexity : O(n)

Comment: Most of the time, `yourarray[i] + ""` evaluates to `[object Object]` :)

Comment: well if a such case is verified then `toString()` will make the job

Comment: Yes, this solution needs `toString()` implemented for all the objects in the array.